# Different values of $A^n$ using Cayley-Hamilton Theorem And Direct Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cayley-hamilton

Let's say there's a matrix A

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -4\\
    1 & -1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now I want to find $A^n$

I tried the following two methods but get different answers. Any solution ?

**By Direct Multiplication:**

$$
A^2= \begin{pmatrix}
    5 & -8\\
    2 & -3\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
A^3= \begin{pmatrix}
    7 & -12\\
    3 & -5\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
A^4= \begin{pmatrix}
    9 & -16\\
    4 & -7\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Observing the pattern

$$
A^n= \begin{pmatrix}
    2n+1 & -4n\\
    n & 1-2n\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Using Cayley-Hamilton Theorem:**

The characteristic equation of the matrix A is

$$
(\lambda-1)^2=0
$$

Using Cayley-Hamilton Theorem:

$$
(A-I)^2=0
$$

$$\implies A=I$$
$$\implies A^n=I$$

Now clearly
$$
I \neq \begin{pmatrix}
    2n+1 & -4n\\
    n & 1-2n\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is correct ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(A-I)^{2}=0$ does not imply that $A=I$.

[For example, $M=\left[\begin{array}{llll}0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0   \end{array}\right]$  is a matrix whose square is $0$. Bur $M$ itself is not $0$].

C-H Theorem gives $A^{2}=2A-I$. A simple induction argument gives $A^{n}=nA-(n-1)I$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks! @Kavi Rama Murthy. Can this question be solved using Cayley Hamilton Theorem ?

Comment: @Jay Yes, $A^{2}=2A-I$ and this can be used to compute $A^{n}$ for any $n$.

Comment: Could you please include that approach in your answer ? Thanks again.

Comment: Use induction to show that $A^{n}=nA-(n-1)I.$